# Wordpress. Submit form after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

On my wordpress site, before submit form, I'm saving in DB data. After that, I need to submit page form.
**JS:**

```
    $('#submit').bind('click',function(e){
        var cm_id = $('#campaign_id').val();
        var cm_name = $('#campaign_name').val();
        var cm_description = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
        var cm_background = $('#upload_image').val();

        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#campaign_form');
        if (cm_id == ''){
            data = {
                action: 'cm_save',
                aj_name: cm_name,
                aj_description: cm_description,
                aj_background: cm_background,
            };
        }
        else{
            data = {
                action: 'cm_update',
                aj_id: cm_id,
                aj_name: cm_name,
                aj_description: cm_description,
                aj_background: cm_background,
            };
        }

        $.post(ajaxurl, data).done(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $(form).submit();
        }).error(function(response){
                console.log(response);
        });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
        <form id="campaign_form" action="options.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php settings_fields('campaign_options'); ?>
        <?php //wp_nonce_field('update-options');?>
        <table class="form-table">

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Enable Campaign Mode:</th>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="campaign_enable" name="campaign_enable"
                           value="1" <?php checked('1', get_option('campaign_enable')); ?> /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Campaign Type:</th>
                <td><label><input type="radio" id="campaign_type" name="campaign_type" <?php if(get_option('campaign_type') == 'block') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="block" />Layer with block</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" id="campaign_type" name="campaign_type" <?php if(get_option('campaign_type') == 'layer') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="layer" />Only layer</label></td>
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top" id="campaign_days_row" <?php if(get_option('campaign_type') != 'layer') echo 'style="display: none;"'; ?> >
                <th scope="row">Show layer again after(d.):</th>
                <td><input type="text" size="5" id="campaign_days" name="campaign_days" value="<?php echo get_option('campaign_days'); ?>"" /> days</td>
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Success message:</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="campaign_success_message" name="campaign_success_message" size="50"
                           value="<?php echo get_option('campaign_success_message'); ?>"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top" style="border: 1px solid #D1CCCC">
                <th style="padding: 0"></th><td style="padding: 0"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row">Select Campaign:</th>
                <td>
                    <select id="campaign_list" name="campaign_list" value="<?php esc_attr_e( get_option('campaign_id') ); ?>" style="width: 50%;">
                        <option value="new" style="background: #ECECEC" <?php selected( '' == get_option('campaign_id') ); ?>>New Campaign</option>
                        <?php
                        if ( $campaign_list ):
                            foreach ($campaign_list as $_item): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $_item['id'] ?>" <?php selected( $_item['id'] == get_option('campaign_id') ); ?>><?php echo $_item['name'] ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;
                        endif; ?>
                    </select>
                    <img src="<?php echo admin_url('/images/wpspin_light.gif'); ?>" class="waiting" id="cm_loading" style="display: none;" />
                    <p><input type="submit" class="button-secondary" value="Remove from list" id="cm_remove" style="display: none" /></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <input type="hidden" id="campaign_id" name="campaign_id" value="<?php echo get_option('campaign_id') ?>">
            <tr valign="top" class="campaign-row">
                <th scope="row">Campaign Name:</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="campaign_name" name="campaign_name"
                           value="<?php echo get_option('campaign_name'); ?>"/></td>
            </tr>


            <tr valign="top" class="campaign-row">
                <th scope="row">Background:</th>
                <td><label for="upload_image">
                        <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="campaign_background"
                               value="<?php echo get_option('campaign_background'); ?>"/>
                        <input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image"/>
                        <br/>Enter an URL or upload an image for the campaign background.
                    </label><br>
                    <img id="upload_image_path" src="<?php echo get_option('campaign_background'); ?>" height="75">
                </td>
            </tr>

          <?php
          $settings = array(
            'teeny' => true,
            'textarea_rows' => 15,
            'tabindex' => 1
            ); ?>

            <tr valign="top" class="campaign-row">
                <th scope="row">Campaign Description:</th>
                <td><?php wp_editor((get_option('campaign_description'))    , 'campaign_description', $settings); ?></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="new_option_name,some_other_option,option_etc"/>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
function cm_save_ajax(){

global $wpdb;

if (isset($_POST['aj_name']) && !empty($_POST['aj_name'])){
    $name = $_POST['aj_name'];
    $description =  $_POST['aj_description'];
    $background = $_POST['aj_background'];

    $wpdb->insert('wp_campaigns',
        array(
            'name'  => $name,
            'description' => $description,
            'background' => $background
        ),
        array(
            '%s', '%s', '%s'
        )
    );

    $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
    update_option('campaign_id', $lastid );

    echo $lastid;

    //echo $wpdb->show_errors();
}
//else echo "Not all data is completed";

die();
```

}
add_action('wp_ajax_cm_save', 'cm_save_ajax');

My Ajax request is successful, but form not submitting. What can be the case?

Comment: is `submit_button();` function use jQuery code to load submit button contents?

Comment: Where is the HTML element with id="submit", which gets the JS function bound to it's click event?